# How to find the SKUs which are assigned to Child category but not to Parent category in Magento 2

Tags: mysql, magento2

How to find the SKUs which are assigned to the Child category but not to Parent category in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

SELECT product_id
            FROM catalog_category_product
            WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id
                                  FROM catalog_category_product
                                  WHERE category_id IN (SELECT entity_id
                                                         FROM catalog_category_entity
                                                         WHERE parent_id = " . $parentCategoryId . "))
            GROUP  BY product_id
            HAVING FIND_IN_SET(" . $parentCategoryId . ", GROUP_CONCAT(category_id)) < 1